# Using flatMapGroupsWithState with forEachBatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a streaming spark app, wherein the running stream I'm removing duplicate rows using Stateful Aggregation with `flatMapGroupsWithState`.
But when I used `forEachBatch` on the stream, and used the same functions I created to remove duplicates on stream, it is treating each Batch as an independent entity, and returning duplicates only among that single Micro Batch.

Code:

```
case class User(name: String, userId: Integer)
case class StateClass(totalUsers: Int)

    def removeDuplicates(inputData: Dataset[User]): Dataset[User] = {
      inputData
        .groupByKey(_.userId)
        .flatMapGroupsWithState(OutputMode.Append, GroupStateTimeout.ProcessingTimeTimeout)(removeDuplicatesInternal)
    }

    def removeDuplicatesInternal(id: Integer, newData: Iterator[User], state: GroupState[StateClass]): Iterator[User] = {
      if (state.hasTimedOut) {
        state.remove() // Removing state since no same UserId in 4 hours
        return Iterator()
      }
      if (newData.isEmpty)
        return Iterator()

      if (!state.exists) {
        val firstUserData = newData.next()
        val newState = StateClass(1) // Total count = 1 initially
        state.update(newState)
        state.setTimeoutDuration("4 hours")
        Iterator(firstUserData) // Returning UserData first time
      }
      else {
        val newState = StateClass(state.get.totalUsers + 1)
        state.update(newState)
        state.setTimeoutDuration("4 hours")
        Iterator() // Returning empty since state already exists (Already sent this UserData before)
      }
    }
```

Input Stream I used is `userStream`.
Above functions works fine when I directly pass stream to it.

```
val results = removeDuplicates(userStream)
```

But when I do something like:

```
userStream
.writeStream
.foreachBatch { (batch, batchId) => writeBatch(batch) } 

def writeBatch(batch: Dataset[User]): Unit = {
  val distinctBatch = removeDuplicates(batch)
}
```

I get distinct User data only within that Micro Batch. But I want it to be distinct overall across 4 hour timeout.
For Eg:

```
If 1st batch has UserIds (1, 3, 5, 1), and second batch has UserIds (2, 3, 1). 
Expected Behaviour: 
  Output: 1st Batch = (1, 3, 5) and 2nd Batch = (2)
My Output: 1st Batch = (1, 3, 5) and 2nd Batch = (2, 3, 1)
```

How can I enable it to use the same State throughout? Right now, it is treating each micro-batch different, and creating a separate state for each batch.

PS: Problem is not limited to getting duplicates on Stream, I need to use forEachBatch for some computations on Micro batches, and remove duplicates before writing.

For Running test script, refer this: https://ideone.com/nZ5pq2

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is actually expected one.

`flatMapGroupsWithState` leverages state store only when the query is streaming one. (For batch query, it doesn't even create a state store because it's not necessary.) Once you call `forEachBatch`, the provided `batch` parameter is no longer continuous one across batches - consider it as a dataset from batch query, which the batch means "a" micro-batch.

So you still need to pass your streaming dataset to `removeDuplicate`, or have your own way to deduplicate records across batches in `forEachBatch`.

Comment: How can I deduplicate records across batches with forEachBatch then? Can you share any such way? Any way I could handle failures too, that is, it should checkpoint that intermediate state and pick up from where it left on code restart?