# Get all records within a window in spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I've a streaming application in structured streaming , I want to get all the records within a defined window (this is a event time window), when I am trying to use groupby(window) and use aggregate as count , I'm not able to fetch all the columns.

```
        val windowSpec = window($"timestamp", " minute","1 minutes")

        // Perform the grouping and aggregation
        val windowedDF = timestampedDF
                .withColumn("window", windowSpec)
                .groupBy($"window")
                .count()
```

How can I get all the records within a defined window and without using an agg. functions ?

I tried [Using flatMapGroupsWithState with forEachBatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65604303/using-flatmapgroupswithstate-with-foreachbatch)
this solution but stuck in same I need to use forEachBatch for some computations on Micro batches.